# How to send DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) information using VBA 64-bit?

Tags: excel, vba, dde

SumatraPDF is a light and fast PDF viewer.
One can control SumatraPDF with DDE commands.
https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/DDE-Commands.

I would like to use VBA to control SumatraPDF.

And here is a demo from Microsoft for DDE application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ddeinitiate
I tested it in Excel VBA (64bit).
The error message always says `Type mismatch` for the line `Application.DDEExecute channelNumber, "[FILEPRINT]"`.
I think I need to convert `longPtr` type `channelNumber`  to `long` type.
Could you help  to point it out how to do this? Thanks.

** Demo script for DDE**

### Case1

`Dim channelNumber As LongPtr`,  the line `Application.DDEExecute` will have `type mismatch` error.

```vb
Sub testdde()
Dim channelNumber As LongPtr
channelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate( _
 app:="WinWord", _
 topic:="C:\WINWORD\FORMLETR.DOC")
Application.DDEExecute channelNumber, "[FILEPRINT]"
Application.DDETerminate channelNumber
End Sub
```

## Update 20240210

Using K J's code, it works for 64-bit SumatraPDF.

## Upadate 20240211

How to select the target window is another challenge.
As the below image shows, one has to choose the correct channel to pass the message. `topic` is one of these parameters to narrow down the channel.
In the post here, it says that `topic` is used to `Describe **something** in the application to which you are opening a channel, usually a document of that application.`. But what does **something** stands for, it's not very clearly documented.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ddeinitiate
[image: Select data source]

Comment: `Application.DDEInitiate` returns a Long, not a LongPtr.  Just change the `Dim`.

Comment: Actually I have done it before asking. And if `dim channelNumber As Long` , the error message `type mismatch` will appear for the line `1channelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate` .

Comment: One of the reason that causes ` type mismatch` error could be that the target window can not be found, either due to not open or can't be found with the `app` and `topic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note I am using 32 bit VBA with 32 bit SumatraPDF but you should never try to cross the 32/64bit security boundary. So for 64 bit VBA only use 64 bit SumatraPDF. It should work for most users, either portable or installed.

To open a file you will need SumatraPDF active and thus actively listening. However, you can command line launch with the first file, then DDE control the viewing.

You need to watch out for imbedded quotes in VBA.

Sometimes it pays to open a secondary file before close the previous one otherwise there may be a time period without either.

```
Sub Sumatrapdf()
'
' Sumatrapdf Macro
' testdde()
'

Dim channelNumber As Long
channelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate( _
 app:="SUMATRA", _
 topic:="control")
Application.DDEExecute channelNumber, "[Open(" & """C:\temp\Burj Khalifa (8).pdf""" & ", 1, 1, 0)]"
Application.DDETerminate channelNumber
End Sub
```

[image]

Many commands without imbedded quotes are much easier, such as

```
Application.DDEExecute channelNumber, "[CmdClose]"
```

will close the current tab. For efficiency avoid closing the app fully, as it can not respond until fully active in memory.

Comment: It works well with 64-bit SumatraPDF! Thanks for your help.

Comment: may I ask a further question, that is how to get the ** only one** channel of SumatraPDF? I only opened one instance of SumatraPDF, but everytime I run the code, there is pop-up list with two items to be selected. The items are `SUMATRA|control` and `SUMATRA|`.  The pop-up window snapshot is shown in the main post above.